# Updating to SQL Server Driver 11.0 in DNS-Less Connection String Not Working

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, connection-string

I'm trying to figure out why this driver works:

```
stConnect = "ODBC;Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & stServer & ";Database=" & stDatabase & ";Trusted_Connection=True;"
```

...but this updated driver doesn't:

```
stConnect = "ODBC;Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=" & stServer & ";Database=" & stDatabase & ";Trusted_Connection=True;"
```

This is Access 365 Version 2211

Is there something on the SQL Server I need to update?

I wouldn't be bothering with this at all except my date data types in SQL server come over as Short Text in Access and I think it's the driver.

Thanks

Comment: Have you installed the SQL Server Native Client 11.0 driver? The legacy "SQL Server" is included with Windows but later ODBC drivers are a separate download and install.

Comment: You may want to move to a newer ODBC driver than Native Client: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I don't see it on my machine, I'll get the admin to install it, thanks!

Comment: As Dan wrote, use the current driver. The Native Client is quite old now.

Comment: Do not install any version of SQL Server Native Client. It has not seen functional updates since SQL Server 2012 and will never see features that support modern SQL Servers, local or Azure-based. If you have legacy applications still using it you should start upgrading them to ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server (or later), or for .NET-based applications use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.

Comment: Thanks; will ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server work for DNS-less connections?  Where do I find the executable for this?  Is this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) the same thing you are speaking of?